# Using destructor is for deleting only dynamically allocated arrays or all arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C++ so I am struggling alot with memory management.
I know that when we have a pointer to an array, it means it is dynamically created, so I should delete it later in my destructor. But what if we have a normal array, do I need to include a delete statement in the destructor for this normal array too? or the program will do that automatically?
for example, I have a normal array like this
`int myArray[];`
and in my destructor, should I include this:
`delete[] myArray;`
?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Everyone struggles with dynamic memory management. The trick is to not do it. Just use `std::array`, `std::vector` and if you have to `std::make_unique` to do it for you. If you never write `new` C++ becomes much easier.

Comment: If you use new, then you need to delete, just like if you malloc you need to free.

Comment: To reiterate and emphasize: never write `new` and `delete`. Ever. Just don't do it. Whoever taught you "dynamic arrays" did you a huge disservice. But if you, for some ungodly reason, must use `new`, your program has to execute exactly one `delete` for each `new` (and exactly one `delete[]` for each `new[]`).

Comment: I remember BS saying in one of his talks: "If you have a raw `new` in your code, you have a memory leak" (refering to the fact that just matching the number of `new`s with the number of `delete`s isnt sufficient). Managing memory manually correctly is extremely difficult even for experienced ones. The trick is not to become a master in managing memory, but to become a master in not managing memory ;)

Comment: @user463035818 There is a frustrating catch-22: One needs to grok manual memory management to fully understand just how bad idea it is to do so. If beginners aren't (eventually) taught to do it, some of them will inevitably think it's not so bad, since they don't know of all the traps yet.

Comment: @eerorika true, only because I had to learn the lesson the hard way, now I can truly appreciate every way of avoiding it ;)

Comment: @eerorika the operative word is eventually.

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah I know, but we are forced to learn manual memory management in our course.

Comment: @n.m. Well I can't do anything but to learn it somehow. University rules, haha

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Thanks man, got it

Comment: @nwp We are not allowed to use vector and array, thats why I need to do it the hard way. myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if we have a normal array, do I need to include a delete statement in the destructor for this normal array too? or the program will do that automatically? for example, I have a normal array like this `int myArray[];` and in my destructor, should I include this: `delete[] myArray;` ?

No. If you don't `new[]` an array, then you don't need to `delete[]` it. Everything else is done automatically. This is why using `std::array`, `std::vector` etc. is so great: There is no need to write `new[]` when you use them, so you don't have to worry that you maybe forgot a `delete[]`.

> *"I know that when we have a pointer to an array, it means it is dynamically created"*

That is not correct. You can take a pointer to basically anything, including stack variables. Dynamic allocation generally gives you back a pointer (which is probably where the confusion stems from) but not every pointer comes from dynamic allocation. Consider this:

```
void foo()
{
    int a;
    int* b = &a; // No dynamic allocation.
}
```

Again, since there is no `new` here, there should be no `delete`.

Comment: Maybe mention stack memory and free store memory?

Comment: Thanks alot, I got it now. I would surely try to avoid using `new` and `delete` but the thing is I have to learn it for my university lessons. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> I know that when we have a pointer to an array, it means it is dynamically created

No. That induction is not correct. A pointer can also point to non-dynamically created arrays.

> so I should delete it later in my destructor.

If your class instance is responsible for destruction of that array then destructor is indeed one place where that should probably be done.

> do I need to include a delete statement in the destructor for this normal array too? for example, I have a normal array like this int myArray[];

No. Only objects created with `new` are destyroyed with `delete`. And only objects created with `new[]` are destroyed with `delete[]`. Not anything else.

> or the program will do that automatically?

Yes.

Objects with automatic storage duration are destroyed automatically at the end of the scope where they are declared. That is what the name of the storage class comes from. Objects with static storage duration are destroyed after `main` returns. Temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression (unless their lifetime is extended by binding the object to a reference). Member variables are destroyed when the super (not meaning base class in this context) object is destroyed.

Only dynamically created objects must be destroyed manually.

---

While it is useful to learn how it is done, there is quite rarely need to do manual memory management in C++. The standard library provides containers that do the hard work for you. Instead of dynamically creating an array, one would typically use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it completely now.

Answer (score 1):

Memory management isn't easy for anyone, especially to those who are new to C++. I recommend looking into the terms `stack` and `heap`, which should hopefully clarify some things up.

> I know that when we have a pointer to an array, it means it is dynamically created, so I should delete it later in my destructor.

This isn't exactly true, a pointer is just a variable that holds the address (where a variable lives) of something. You can make a pointer to any variable like this:

```
int a = 5;
int *aPtr = &a;
```

This doesn't mean that `a` or `aPtr` are dynamic.

However a pointer made like this would be dynamic and needs to be deleted:

```
int *aPtr = new int(5);
```

The biggest difference here is the `new` keyword. `new` makes dynamic memory (what is put onto the heap). Every time you use the `new` keyword, you should use the `delete` keyword to match with it.

> But what if we have a normal array, do I need to include a delete statement in the destructor for this normal array too? or the program will do that automatically? for example, I have a normal array like this `int myArray[];` and in my destructor, should I include this: `delete[] myArray;` ?

No, you wouldn't need to call `delete[] myArray;` because this array would be made on the stack. What I mean by that is that when you return out of the function that made this array, the array would be cleaned out of memory.

An alternative to manually managing memory is to use the `std::array`, `std::vector`, or even smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` that clean themselves up  after the reference to it is gone.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I was confused with these. The thing is we are not allowed to use `std::vector` or `std::array` , so thats why I have to manually do it.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from the answers is that I don't need to `delete` anything if `new` is not triggered. Same goes to `delete[]` and `new[]` . Normally created arrays like the one in my question `int myArray[]` is not dynamically created, so it does not need to be dynamically deleted in destructor, meaning, the compiler will do the deleting part for me. Thanks all